# phonegap ios fixed input field on virtual keyboard

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

'm creating an phonegap application with jquery Mobile. in my app a fixed input Field appear on the top of virtual keyboard , thats work fine in android , but in IOS when virtual keyboard appears it not work.

my issue is smaller to this  [IOS Fixed footer toolbar breaks on virtual keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557780/ios-7-fixed-footer-toolbar-breaks-on-virtual-keyboard)

**js**

```
header_height = $('.main-header').height();
footer_height = $('.footer').height();
footer_input_height = $('.fixed_bottom').height();

$('.fixed_bottom').css('bottom',footer_height+'px');
$('#messages .ui-panel-wrapper').css('padding-bottom','inherit');

$("input, textarea").blur(function() {
    $("[data-role=footer]").show('','',function(){
        $('#messages').css('padding-bottom',footer_height+'px');
        $('#messages .ui-panel-wrapper').css('padding-bottom','inherit');
        $('.fixed_bottom').css('bottom',footer_height+'px');
    });
});
$("input, textarea").focus(function() {
    $("[data-role=footer]").hide('','',function(){
        $('#messages').css('padding-bottom','0px');
        $('#messages .ui-panel-wrapper').css('padding-bottom','0px');
        $('.fixed_bottom').css('bottom','0px');                 
    });
})
```

**CSS**

```
#messages .fixed {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
}
#messages .fixed_bottom {
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

screenshot in android[image: android]

screenshoot in Iphone [image: Iphone]